# Import XML file greater than 2 GB to DB2

Tags: xml, db2

I need to import this XML file into a sample database table. The XML file is over 3 GB and as such, it looks like the traditional importing mechanisms in DbVisualizer is unable to import this XML file. Please provide information on how such large files are imported into a DB2 table.

Comment: I don't think DB2 will allow you to import or store an XML document larger than 2 GB. Consider compressing it and storing as BLOB.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using db2 version 10.5 and it does allow over 2GB. I wrote a java program that was able to stream the 3.8 GB of data in the table. It took a while but it works. I hope it is not a hassle to create indexes on the xml because its a lot of data to index.

Comment: This is interesting. XML column size limit indeed is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation. I guess when using a GUI client, XML is represented on the client side by a character data type (`VARCHAR` or `CLOB`), which do have limits (`CLOB` cannot be larger than 2 GB, for example).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to use the [DB2 `LOAD` utility](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008305.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F3-6-2-4-83), with the `xml from` option.

Your normal row data is stored in one file (presumably in CSV format), with the XML column containing locators to the XML data stored in one or more files.  The XML column in your main data file has locators, like:

```
"<XDS FIL='po.del.001.xml' OFF='0' LEN='373' />"
```

Where `po.del.001.xml` is an XML file in the path you specify with the `xml from` option, and `OFF`/`LEN` specify the offset and length of individual XML documents within the file.  (You could have a separate file for each XML document or multiple documents within each file).

Comment: When I try that it failed with this error: SQL2206N An SQL error "901" occured while inserting a row into the table. SQL0901N The sql statement or command failed because of a database system error. (Reason "".) SQLSTATE=58004 SQL3110N The utility has completed processing. "1" rows were read from the input file.